# RowCommand highlight a row and go back to previous row color

Tags: asp.net, gridview, vb.net-2010, aspxgridview

I have a gridview that highlight a row when its clicked. What I want to do is set the previous selected row to its previous row color and changed the color of the new selected row. How can I achieve that? Please Help. Thank you.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePane1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" class = "grd-view table table-hover" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gridview1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:GridView>   
</ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>



 Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                r.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';"
                r.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
                r.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
                r.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & r.RowIndex, True)
            End If
        Next
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    GridView1.Rows(index).Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#f1f0f0")
End Sub
```

Comment: is it a large gridview  i.e. having large number of rows ?

Comment: @sami yes. Also I edited my codes above.